# sql server 2012 connection using Uid and Pwd defaulting to Windows Auth

Tags: sql-server, authentication, sql-server-2012, database-connection

I have an Excel workbook that will query a SQL Server 2012 database using VBA.  Many users will temporarily use this workbook so I created a generic ID with SQL Server credentials only.  Some of the users can execute the VBA and retrieve data without a problem.  When other users try, the VBA ignores the provided connection string using the generic user and password and provides their windows credentials.  Why are they sending their windows credentials instead of the credentials provided in the connection string?  How do I force the connection to use the provided Uid and Pwd?

The error message is 

Connection Failed: 

SQL State '28000'

SQL Server Error 18456

...Login failed for user '*Domain\Userid*'

The database server security is set up to use both SQL Server and Windows authentication.

The connection string is:

```
connstring = "ODBC;Driver=SQL Server;Server=" & Server & ";Database=" & DBTarget & ";Uid=" & Whoisit & ";Pwd=" & Authword & ";"
```

They're all running Windows 7 Enterprise and Office 2010.
They're all on the same network domain.

Comment: Restart SQL Server Service as if you set both SQL Server and Windows authentication lately.

Comment: @Bavishi PN The security settings have been that way since the creation of the server. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Due to a pressing need, this morning we created official windows authenticated userds in the database for these users.  Not a fix, just a work-around.  It's still odd that the original method worked for some and not others.